# Get IPv4 Address of client in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I log the 'socket' object during socket.on('connection'), I get the following information:
`_peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 57535 }`

How do I change the family to IPv4 during socket connection?

Answer (score 2):

I was testing around and found that on the client if I use

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8000', { transports: ['websocket']});
```

the `socket.handshake.address` returns `::1`

If I use

```
var socket = io('http://server_ip:8000', { transports: ['websocket']});
```

the `socket.handshake.address` return `::ffff:ipv4address`

Answer (score 2):

When you create an http instance, make sure you bind your connection to an IPv4 address.
Example:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8000');
});
```

That should do the trick. :)

Comment: to anyone struggling with this, pay attention in particular to the `'0.0.0.0'` part

Answer (score 1):

This should listen on IPv4; Try it and let me know...

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer();
server.on('connection', handleConnection);

server.listen({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  exclusive: true
  }, function() {
     console.log('server listening to %j', server.address());
});
```

Output:

```
server listening to {"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":8000}
```